# Errors during first flashing of the android IoT image for Pico Pro Maker Kit

Tags: iot, android-build, android-things

Hello Im trying to create initial flash/build for IoT development following this tutorial https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d.html#flashing_the_image

Im sorry if my questions is too broad, this is my first IoT attempt,  but it seems to me like I have a wrong setup, beacuse Im **constantly running into new errors**.

Im stuck at step 2.4 Execute the flash-all.sh. Running

```
sudo ./flash-all.sh
```

I got this in my logs:

> ./flash-all.sh: line 52: ./u-boot.imx: Permission denied

If I change permissons

```
chmod 777 u-boot.imx
```

I got

> ./flash-all.sh: line 52: ./u-boot.imx: cannot execute binary file:
>   Exec format error

I already solved several other issues which werent described in tutorial, including

1. I have to run script as sudo, otherwise I got

> < waiting for any device >

2. I had to rewrite fastboot command to $(which fastboot) inside flash-all.sh (same with flash and bootloader), otherwise commands are unknown even thought I added them to PATH

I am using

- ubuntu 16.14,
- android studio with installed sdk 26
- Pico Pro Maker Kit with Pico i.MX7 Dual Development Board

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> I had to rewrite fastboot command to $(which fastboot) inside flash-all.sh (same with flash and bootloader), otherwise commands are unknown even thought I added them to PATH

This seems like it might be the root of the problem, as somehow the subsequent lines for each command are not being parsed as arguments for fastboot, but rather as their own executable commands.

You also shouldn't need to run the script with `sudo`. This might be why you can run `which fastboot` successfully (which would indicate it's in your PATH), but the script cannot see this.